# Pega valor de um input executar função e retorna em outra input

Tags: javascript, html

Estou querendo efetuar uma função bem simples, que é pegar o CPF de uma input, retirar os pontos e traços e retornar o valor em outra input sem os pontos e traços.

A primeira parte consegui fazer, porem não sei como fazer para retornar a função na outra input.

```js
let botao = document.querySelector("#botao");
let retornaCpf = document.querySelector("#retornaCpf")

botao.onclick = function() {
  let cpf_com_ponto_e_traco = document.querySelector("#cpf-com-ponto-e-traco").value;
  let cpf_sem_ponto_e_traco = cpf_com_ponto_e_traco.replace(".", "").replace(".", "").replace("-", "");
  
  alert(cpf_sem_ponto_e_traco);
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cpf-com-ponto-e-traco">
<input type="text" id="retornaCpf">
<button id="botao">Pegar CPF</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simples:

```
retornaCpf.value = cpf_sem_ponto_e_traco;
```

Ou seja, para pegar o valor você lê o `value` do primeiro input, e para preencher o outro você define o seu `value`.

Comment: Muito obrigado, deu certinho.